# pythonでselenium(Firefox)を使ったスクレイピングでエラー

Tags: firefox, selenium, python3

pythonでselenium(Firefox)を使ったスクレイピングをしているのですが、
httpsのページにアクセスするとエラーになってしまい、困っております。

httpのページにはアクセスできます。

解決策をご存知の方がおられましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。

Firefoxを使うのが必須条件です。

環境

---

centos6(vagrant)

python3.5

selenium (3.0.2)

Xvfb

firefox 45

エラー内容

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "cer.py", line 17, in 
    driver.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error loading page

エラーになるソースコード

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# 証明書の警告を無視する
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
profile.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = False

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

ウィルス対策ソフトを停止するとアクセスできるようになりました。。。